# How to pronounce mathematical words correctly

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

This seems silly. But I don't know where else to ask this.

Is there a good site for mathematical words pronunciation ?

Comment: I would say that such questions do belong on this site.

Comment: When you're lucky, the Merriam-Webster Unabridged will have the answer. Less frequently, the Merriam-Webster website, which has their Collegiate Dictionary on it. See here about MSE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/questions-about-how-to-read-mathematical-notation